# Deserializing JSON when there are properties with collections

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I have successfully used Spring & Jackson as follows,

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass> result = restTemplate.exchange(
                    MYURL, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                    MyClass.class);
```

Here MyClass is a POJO where there is a field mapped with each field in the JSON.

And also I could map the situations where there are many JSON "objects"

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(MYURL, MyClass[].class);
```

This parses a simple array of objects and it worked fine.

But now I am in a more complicated situation. I have a JSON like this.

```
{
    "id": "1998",
    "items": {
        "1": {
            "map": {
                "1": "1.2",
                "2": "2.5",
                "3": "6.1",
                "4": "5.4",
                "5": "9.7",
                "6": "4.23",
                "7": "7.65",
                "8": "1.1",
                "9": "8.5",
                "10": "6.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the "items" array you can have another items as "2" or "3". Each of them contains a different "map". I wan't to map these information into an Object.

Obviously the array approach above does not work work since there is a property "id" there.

How can I design a POJO for this? Do I need to write a Custom Deserializer for this?

Answer (score 0):

ResponseObject with properties:

```
Long id;
Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
```

where Item object could be:

```
Long id;
Map<String, String> mapItems = new HashMap<String, String>();
```